# FontAwesome Icons in Anchors Wider Fit to Content

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, bootstrap-4

I am trying to have two clickable icons on the right side of a list item. However, for some reason the anchors containing the icons stretch so wide (without padding or margins) that the click zones overlap.

Is this an issue with my fontawesome icons? Or is it some other problem I can't find.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mg6d8s75/1/

HTML:

```
<ul class="list-group ui-sortable" id="todolist">
  <li class="ui-sortable-handle">
    <div class="prettycheckbox">
      <div class="prettycheckbox-success">
        <input class="todocheckbox" type="checkbox" id="checkbox336" aria-label="...">
        <label for="checkbox336">
          <span>I'm a task!</span>
          <a href="#notification-modal" id="notification336" class="notification-button pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-task-id="336" data-due-date="1111-11-11">
            <span><i class="fa fa-bell-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
          </a>
          <a href="" class="deletebutton pull-right" id="delete336">
            <span><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
          </a>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.deletebutton {
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}

.notification-button {
  top: 10px;
  right: 30px;
  position: absolute;
}

/* TodoList Checkboxes */

.prettycheckbox input[type="checkbox"]:hover:not(:checked) ~ label {
  color: #888;
}

.prettycheckbox input[type="checkbox"]:hover:not(:checked) ~ label:before {
  content: '\2714';
  text-indent: .9em;
  color: #C2C2C2;
}

.prettycheckbox div {
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.prettycheckbox label {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #D1D3D4;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.prettycheckbox input[type="checkbox"]:empty {
  display: none;
}

.prettycheckbox input[type="checkbox"]:empty ~ label {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  text-indent: 3.25em;
  margin-top: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}

.prettycheckbox input[type="checkbox"]:empty ~ label:before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 2.5em;
  background: #D1D3D4;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prettycheckbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label {
  color: #31B44A;
}

.prettycheckbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label:before {
  content: '\2714';
  text-indent: .9em;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.prettycheckbox input[type="checkbox"]:focus ~ label:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #999;
}

.prettycheckbox-success input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label:before {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
}

#todolist > li {
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: Wow, sorry for the title typo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the links out of your label and it seems to fix the problem

```
<ul class="list-group ui-sortable" id="todolist">
  <li class="ui-sortable-handle">
    <div class="prettycheckbox">
      <div class="prettycheckbox-success">
        <input class="todocheckbox" type="checkbox" id="checkbox336" aria-label="...">
        <label for="checkbox336">
          <span>I'm a task!</span>
        </label>
        <a href="#notification-modal" id="notification336" class="notification-button pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-task-id="336" data-due-date="1111-11-11">
          <i class="fa fa-bell-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="" class="deletebutton pull-right" id="delete336">
          <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I also removed the spans as their unnecessary.

Comment: For some reason I also had to adjust the position of the anchor classes from absolute to relative. Otherwise multiple li items would appear on top of each other at the top. However, taking them out of the label was key to solving the width issue so thank you!